# zend facebook auth overwriting local login storage

Tags: facebook, zend-framework

I have an app with a local login system.  What I am trying to do is allow the user to connect their facebook account to their account.  I am using Zend Auth for my main local login and a facebook auth by Michael Krotscheck.

I can connect with facebook fine but because I am using Zend_Auth the facebook data is over writing the main local login storage.  All I need is the users email and facebook id and insert them into my users table.

The code below shows how it all works, I do not know another alternative than using Zend Auth for the facebook login.  Anybody had the same issues?  Advice would be very helpful.

```
$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();

    $adapter = $this->_getFacebookAdapter();

    $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $toStore = array('identity' => $auth->getIdentity());

            // for facebook
            $msgs = $result->getMessages();
            $toStore['properties'] = (array) $msgs['user'];
            $toStore['provider'] = "facebook";

            $auth->getStorage()->write($toStore);

            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Successful authentication');
            //return $this->_redirect('/index/index');

            // Check if the User is in our dB
            //$users = new My_Model_Users();
            //$userTrue = $users->checkUserExists($userId,$providerName);
            Zend_Debug::dump($toStore);
            Zend_Debug::dump($this->_helper->user());

        } else {                                                

            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Failed authentication');
            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger($result->getMessages());
            //return $this->_redirect('/index/index');
        }
```

J

Answer (score 0):

After more trawling stackoverflow I found a solution.

[Multiple Instances (2) of Zend_Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4318599/multiple-instances-2-of-zend-auth)

Basically created my own Auth class and removed the singleton pattern in Zend_Auth, this allowed me to create another instance.

J